# Client authentication using the pfx not working

Tags: certificate-authority, openssl

I have a requirement to generate the client certificates(pfx) files from another server certificate which are provided by a CA.

Firstly I tested the following based on

http://www.jayway.com/2014/09/03/creating-self-signed-certificates-with-makecert-exe-for-development/

I followed the steps mentioned in this and created a CA, Server pfx and the Client pfx.
Added the CA to the Trusted Root in Local computer in the server machine, also the Server pfx into the Personal in the Local Computer.
Binded the Server pfx to the https 443 port in the IIS to my website and set the Require SSL option.

Imported the Client pfx in the Current User in the client machine and accessed the website. The website asked to use the Client certificate and it works

But my actual requirement is that I will be provided with Server pfx or p12 and not the CA cer or CA pvk.
I added the Server pfx to the Trusted Root CA  and tried creating the Client pfx using the Server pvk and Server cert files. Also modified the SSL in server to bind to this server certificate.
But the Client pfx which I created when imported to the client machine Current User, and accessed the website it is giving me access denied .
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

Am I doing something wrong or is it not possible to create client pfx just using the server pfx or p12 without having the CA files ?